# Define a js function inside another js function

Tags: javascript

I've recently found this code snippet:

```
function start() {

    function sleep(milliSeconds) {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds);
    }

    sleep(10000);
    return "Hello Start";
}
```

What advantages do we have defining functions this way instead of using a 'traditional' approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `traditional approach`? One function inside another simply works in a different scope.

Comment: The real question is why wouldn't you use [timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: @VisioN for example in java is not possible to define a method inside another, unless using anonymous methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage to doing this is that your function `sleep` is no longer defined at the global scope.  It is scoped to the function `start`.

This is advantageous because putting all of your functions at the global scope, can cause conflicts with other scripts.

There is nothing `traditional` about defining all functions as globals, it is just a bad practice that has been perpetuated.  Reducing your `global` footprint is a good and responsible practice that will reduce conflicts between your scripts and other scripts that may be included in your applications.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with scope. Consider picking up a copy of the recently published [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/) for a great overview of JavaScript. But we can use your browser console to try this (might not work in Internet Explorer, use Chrome):

```
> function start() { function bob() { console.log('bob'); } bob() };
> start()
> bob
> bob()
> ReferenceError: bob is not defined
```

So you can see that the function `bob` inside of `start` is not in scope outside of the `start` function. There are a number of reasons to do this.